# Reading property file in different module

Tags: maven, properties

The static method in my class has to read a property file located in another module.

```
public class Util
{
  private static void readProp()
  {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String fileName = "/appconfig.properties"; //File in another module
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try
    {
      inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(propFileName);
      if (inputStream != null)
       {
         prop.load(inputStream);
       }
    }
            catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The Util method is in module1 while the appconfig.properties is in module2.

The absolute paths for the two is

Util.java :

```
/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/myProject/module1/src/main/java/com/microsoft/e3/cx/service/windows/search/util/Util.java
```

appconfig.properties:

```
/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/myProject/module2/appconfig/base/appconfig.properties
```

The pom of module2 has module1 as a dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>microsoft.module1</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

My inputStream always comes out to be null. I suppose it is because it is unable to locate this file. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Util.getClass().getResourceAsStream("appconfig.properties");
```

Comment: Util.getClass() wouldnt work in a static context. The method is static